# Cannot login after I publish my asp.net web application in IIS 5.1 and 6

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've published my website and tried to host in my localsystem.Im getting the login page but cannot login to my application.When i click the submit button in the login page,the page simply refreshes and comesback.The page is not showing any error like `'invalid username or password'` which i've set for not proper login

Im using `visualstudio 2008` and `iis 5.1`. What could be cause of this error ??

Now i installed iis6,but still having the same problem ...........

Comment: What is your web.config settings ? (the login settings)

Comment: Why are you still using IIS 5.1?

Comment: @Kaf For local debug, what else. I do the same on XP

Comment: For local debug? Upgrade to IIS6 which is native to XP. IIS5 hasn't been supported in years... years and years.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson Ok, this is something that I didn't know, that iis6 can be installed on XP. Of course now is better to install the windows 7, or 8 than just update to iis6 :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything after XP SP1 shipped with IIS6. IIS 5 is more than ten years old

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson Well, I have right, windows xp 32 bit can only run 5.1, Windows XP 64bit have the iis6. http://forums.iis.net/t/1156371.aspx

Comment: Plenty of production platforms are running IIS 5 (sadly) so I'm guessing that  IIS 5.1 isn't the source of the issue. Regardless, there isn't enough information in the original post to help solve the issue. Knowing the web.config and login framework (forms auth vs nt) for example is vital. Also, show us the code the page is running on post back, please.

Comment: Ugh. Please consider using an operating system that was created in the last ten years.

Comment: @ksg This have nothing to do with iis, have to do how you have install the form settings on the web.config. If the cookie fails to enter, than the login fails, show us your web.config for more help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the built in asp.net membership and roles you will have to set up new users and roles for the published website because the ones currently in your database will only be valid for the development application; they will have a different applicationId. You would normally do this is IIS but I've never used 5.1 so no idea how to on there.